# Is there a word for the bad smell coming from socks?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any specific English word to refer to the bad smell coming from socks, especially ones that have been unwashed for some time?

Comment: I've heard that called "cheesy-feet" on account of it reeking similarly to the odor off moldy cheese.

Comment: FWIW, much of the odor of really stinky sweat is due to [butyric acid](https://chronicleflask.com/2014/11/29/butyric-acid-a-very-smelly-molecule/).  Though butyric acid smells like vomit, it is a key ingredient in Hersey's chocolate.

Comment: @HotLicks "Hersey's [sic] chocolate"? I've never come across any malodorous chocolate reminding me of vomit, but I venture to put forward my own observation that 'Epoisses', a very smelly cheese from France, meets this exact description. Quel fromage!

Comment: @PeterPoint - Read the article.  Butyric acid is a key flavoring/odorant in many foods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My answer will probably be down-voted, but here goes anyway.

The problem of sweaty feet is called *plantar hyperhydrosis*.  The phenomenon is, strictly speaking, the problem of having overly sweaty feet.  Sweat, or perspiration, does not have an immediate olfactory property (at least not that I'm aware of), but it does emit an unpleasant olfactory component not long after it is exposed to the air after soaking one's socks, for example.

From the little I've read on this far-from-uncommon phenomenon, the technical term *plantar hyperhidrosis* can also be used to describe the egregious smell emanating from the perspiration being wicked by the socks.  The bacteria in the moisture-laden socks mix with the air (and often with the heat generated by exercise and by the temperature at the time) and begin to do their thing.  P.U.!

Comment: This is the closest answer so far to the OP's request for a "*specific* English word to refer to the bad smell coming from socks" (emphasis added).

Answer (score 5):

*Cheesey* probably gets closest.

Comment: Cheesey that means cliched? Why should that describe socks? Could you please add some details?

Comment: I understand this literal reference - I have a friend that calls grated parmesan cheese "Stinky Sock Cheese".

Comment: 'Cheesey' ***is*** a term used to refer to smelly socks, at least in BrE; but I haven't investigated why, how, origin, etc..

Comment: @KristinaLopez Somewhat OT, but others might refer to grated parmesan cheese as "puke cheese" because some think it smells of vomit. ;-)

Comment: Don't wash your socks for a week or two and then compare the smell with that of some ripe fromage of your choice.

Comment: @TrevorD, I've heard that too! Yet we eat and love cheese. lol!

Comment: Yes, certain fermented cheeses have a definite "stinky sock" odor.

Comment: @HotLicks it makes sense, as one of the compounds which produces the smell of BO and stinky feet is is butyric acid, which is also a component of cheese and butter. Butyric acid in small quantities is used as a flavoring, in large quantities it's unpleasant.

Comment: @barbecue - Yeah, I mentioned butyric acid in a comment to the question above.  And I recall in college when someone dropped a small vial of butyric acid on the floor and the place stank to high heaven for days.  In concentrated form it smells very much like vomit.

Comment: @HotLicks I had a bottle of it back in high school, shenanigans ensued.

Answer (score 2):

While not as specific as "plantar hyperhydrosis" (the accepted answer above), the word *funk* also fits (and is far more colloquial). The word has various meanings, the relevant one being, per Merriam-Webster's online dictionary:

> a strong offensive smell[<sup>1</sup>](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/funk)

*Funk* is often used for describing bad smells originating from spoiled food, body odor, and other similarly "distinguished" offensive odors.

Here's a usage example with socks:

> Some kids in orange jumpsuits were in the middle of a soccer game. We stepped up to the sidelines. **The sweaty sock funk was so pungent** I wondered if it slowed the kids down. Two helicopters roared overhead, adding to a breeze across the dirt patch.

[Source](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=_yJSQFNNeAgC&pg=PA301&lpg=PA301&dq=%22sock+funk%22&source=bl&ots=2JOf01DoCG&sig=LYCapCYn6yt8c_jYZdovw8bLJKg&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22sock%20funk%22&f=false) -  *It Happened on the Way to War: A Marine's Path to Peace* by Rye Barcott

Answer (score 0):

STINK   is the most commonly used word.
If it is too severe, you may call it Stench

Comment: I would have said that *stench* is stronger than *stink*; but, that aside, those words merely 'describe' *any* strong smell - they do not specifically describe the smell of unwashed socks as asked by the OP.